# Softer soft parse in oracle using Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, caching, cursor

I have an application written in Visual C# and connected to Oracle database. I have amended all queries(Insert, Select, Update, Delete) inside the application to use Bind Variables to achieve the **soft parse concept in Oracle**.

Amending the queries to use Bind Variables (as shown in the below code) has tremendously helped us to achieve a great application performance. So what we did at this level is called **soft parse**. However, the ultimate solution is to use the **softer soft parse**.

Below is a **dummy method** using Bind Variables in the query statement. (Please note that I intended to iterate 5 times just to see the result in oracle Toad tool since **my target is to let oracle parse the query once and execute it 5 times which is called softer soft parse in oracle** but using the below code, it is being parsed 5 times and executed 5 times which is the soft parse)

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List <OracleParameter> bindVariables = new List<OracleParameter>();
    OracleParameter vCNTRNBR = new OracleParameter();
    vCNTRNBR.ParameterName = "BATCH_ID";
    vCNTRNBR.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
    vCNTRNBR.Size = 8;
    bindVariables.Add(vCNTRNBR);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vCNTRNBR.Value = i.ToString();
        string sel = "SELECT * FROM BATCHTOTAL WHERE BATCHID = :BATCH_ID";
        using (OracleDataReader testReader = this.myEnv.dbcon1.DbmSelect(sel, bindVariables))
        {
            if (testReader != null && testReader.Read())
                s1 = testReader["MERCHANTID"].ToString();
            else
                s1 = "null";
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me achieving the **softer soft parse**. I have checked many articles and blogs saying that cursor cache should be enabled in oracle. We have enabled it but the query is still being parsed 5 times instead of one time. Does this mean that the query is not cached?

Here is a good article talking about statement caching:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/stmtcach.htm#JJDBC28650

Statement caching improves performance by caching executable statements that are used repeatedly, such as in a loop or in a method that is called repeatedly. Starting from JDBC 3.0, JDBC standards define a statement-caching interface.

Statement caching can do the following:

1. Prevent the overhead of repeated cursor creation
2. Prevent repeated statement parsing and creation
3. Reuse data structures in the client

Your help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is method `this.myEnv.dbcon1.DbmSelect` doing? I have never seen it before.

Comment: Hi Wernfried. Thank you for your reply. this.myEnv.dbcon1.DbmSelect is simply a local customized method that executes the select statement